# Notification on UI component reused in UI virtualization

Tags: wpf, ui-virtualization

I am using a Xceed WPF Grid with UI virtualization with horizontal and vertical Scrollbars.  When I use the Scrollbar vertically or horizontally, with reusable UI components (VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"), I want an event or property change other than from the Scrollbar.

Comment: What do you mean by 'than UI components are reuse at that time'? One event you can hook up to is an item's BringIntoView event, which should fire anytime any part of an UI element is scrolled into view.

Comment: UI components resuing means using the VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling". But for each cell how can bind BringIntoView event.

Comment: I'm actually rethinking that suggestion. To answer your question, you would traverse the visual tree to the DataGridCells, iterate through them and assign the handler to their respective RequestBringIntoView events. I have code (with a few slight mods) to do this, but I'm not so sure this is the best way. What are the contents of your cells? Are the contents going to be UI elements as well?

Comment: Actually my problem is if i make background color of a cell and move vertically or horizontally than cell is reused and retain than same color.